# How do I simulate an ideal gas?

Tags: simulations, ideal-gas

I wish to write a simple simulation of an ideal gas, but my maths and how I should have a model based the equation isn't quite up to it. I need some help understanding the relationship between pressure, the amount of the gas, and the temperature (the volume is a constant), not just at one moment, but as one or more of the variables change...

Right now, I have global variables for $P$, $T$ and $n$, and an update loop in my code where I check to see if $T$ has changed. If so, I can solve the ideal gas equation $P = nRT/V$ as the others are unchanged. The results look ok to me. I can warm the tank, and the pressure rises.

Now, if I add or remove some gas, by changing $n$, I am unsure how to change both $P$ and $T$. If I just recalculate $P$,  I can remove gas until the pressure falls to $0$, yet the temp remains constant the whole time. This doesn't seem right, shouldn't there be some temperature drop too?

Can you explain how I should go about improving this simulation?

Comment: I don’t consider what you are doing to be a “simulation” of an ideal gas. To me, a simulation would be one in which you simulate a lot of atoms moving around in a box, bouncing off the walls and each other. They have masses, positions, and velocities. The macroscopic thermodynamic stuff then gets calculated from the microscopic dynamics.

Comment: Perhaps a poor choice of words. It is a black box, where the user can read the pressure, read and adjust temperature, and add or remove gas. Maybe "model" is a better term?

Comment: OK, I understand now what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 3):

> Now, if I add or remove some gas, by changing n, I am unsure how to
>   change both P and T. If I just recalculate P, I can remove gas until
>   the pressure falls to 0, yet the temp remains constant the whole time.
>   This doesn't seem right, shouldn't there be some temperature drop too?

Let the container of the ideal gas be rigid ($V$= constant) and thermally insulated so that there is no heat transfer between the gas in the container and the surroundings, and no change in volume, when you remove some the gas. Under these conditions if you remove some gas from the container then, yes, the temperature should drop too.

Rearranging the ideal gas equation we have

$$\frac{PV}{T}=nR$$

If we hold $V$ constant, and remove say, one half of the moles of gas, then since $R$ is constant the ratio of the new pressure to temperature will also be one half of what it was prior to removal of the gas in order to continue to satisfy the ideal gas equation.

Another way to think about it is when you remove some of the gas from the container,  you also remove some of the internal energy that it possessed in the container, thus lowering the internal energy contents of the container. For an ideal gas the internal energy per mole is directly proportional to its temperature according to

$$U=\frac{3}{2}RT$$

Since the internal energy of an ideal gas depends only on its temperature,  if we reduce the internal energy of the gas by one half by removing one half of the gas, the temperature will be reduced by one half as well. Since the volume is fixed, that means the pressure is reduced by one half as well to satisfy the ideal gas equation.

Hope this helps.

Comment: What is U here?

Comment: Typical symbol for Internal energy

Comment: Is it correct to say then that P, T and n all decrease in a linear fashion until they all reach 0 at the same time?

Comment: @Innovine In theory perhaps, but it is generally acknowledged that absolute zero temperature is not possible thermodynamically. It is my understanding that scientists can experimentally achieve temperatures within a few degrees of absolute zero, but not absolute zero. The lowest temperature in outer space is the cosmic microwave background radiation which according to NASA is 2.725 K.

Comment: Thanks, I can fudge it as it approaches zero for sure. Just wanted to verify I had it right in general

Comment: @Innovine  In that case you had it right in general, under the assumption of constant volume and no heat transfer so that the only reason for a change in internal energy is the removal or addition of gas.

Comment: If i have a filled balloon, which I haven't tied, and I release the mouthpiece and let the air out, as the pressure falls on the inside, is there a change in temperature?

Comment: I've unmarked this as the accepted answer for the moment, as I still don't actually have a satisfying simulation, and a lot more questions.

Comment: @Innovine No problem. But don't you think you should give me a chance to address your latest questions, that are only 25 minutes old ,before unmarking my answer?

Comment: The answer as it stands is inadequate, so its been unmarked.

Comment: @Innovine That's interesting. Your original question didn't talk about a balloon which is not, of course, rigid. My original answer addressed your original question as stated adequately, and you accepted it. Now you are modifying  your question.  If you want to ask a different question, or modify your existing question you should post another question. In any event, since your question appears to be a moving target I have no desire to chase it and therefore have nothing more to add.

Comment: Your answer wasnt sufficient to explain any of it to me, so, no answer. I am not modifying my question, im adding commments. You can check the question edit history if you like.

Comment: @Innovine In the comments is not an appropriate place to ask further questions. If you have more questions you can ask them as separate questions, or ask in chat. That said, whatever answer (if any) you choose to accept is your prerogative.

Comment: I don't see it as a further question, I am posing a question to highlight an unclear aspect of the provided answer. The behavior of heat transfer is still very unclear.

Comment: I know I'm late to the party here, but how does removing half of the gas change the internal energy *per mole*?  The *total* internal energy goes down by a factor of two, but so does the number of moles, so the temperature would remain constant.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use equilibrium states with the ideal gas law to model a change in the moles of gas because equilibrium assumes a closed system with constant mass, but that is clearly not the case here so you will have to use an open system to figure how $T$ and $P$ change with $n$. I will show an example with an ideal gas leaving a vessel with constant volume $V$ to answer your question in the comments that $P$ and $T$ do *not* decrease linearly.

You need an energy balance and a material balance around a control volume (i.e. the tank) and let's assign mass/energy entering the tank be positive and leaving be negative:

$\frac{dn_{cv}U_{cv}}{dt} = -H_{cv}*\dot{n_{out}} \\ \frac{dn_{cv}}{dt}=-\dot{n_{out}}$

In the first equation you can eliminate $n_{cv}U_{cv}$ using:

$nU = nH - nPV$

and eliminate $n_{out}$ using the material balance above to get:

$\frac{d(nH_{cv}-nPV)}{dt} = H_{out}*\frac{dn_{cv}}{dt}$

Then after simplifying and by substituting $dH$ with $C_pdT$, and letting $\gamma = \frac{C_p}{R}$ you get:

$\frac{dT}{T}=(\gamma-1)*\frac{\dot{n_{out}}}{n_{cv}}*dt$

Finally, use the material balance to eliminate $dt$ and after some rearranging you will get:

$\frac{dT}{T}=(\gamma-1)\frac{dn_{cv}}{n_{cv}}$ and integrating from initial to final states yields:

$ln(\frac{T_f}{T_i})=(\gamma-1)ln(\frac{n_f}{n_i})$

So that equation will tell you how the temperature drops as moles of ideal gas are leaving your system. Finally you can relate pressure and temperature by substituting $PV=nRT$ for the moles and after rearranging you will get:

$ln(\frac{T_f}{T_i})=\frac{(\gamma-1)}{\gamma}ln(\frac{P_f}{P_i})$

or

$\frac{T_f}{T_i}=(\frac{P_f}{P_i})^{\frac{(\gamma-1)}{\gamma}}$

So as you can see, the temperature and pressure do not decrease at the same rate and you cannot simply use the ideal gas to solve this problem because the moles of gas leaving are carrying enthalpy (energy) with them as they leave.